# Edit items (hyperlinks) in a repeater with a single edit button

Tags: c#, xml, web, repeater, edit

I've got a repeater which is bound to a List<> generated from an XML file. The file consists of two nodes, ID and Item.

```
<Items><ID>0</ID>
<Item><![CDATA[<a target='blank' href="http://www.cnn.com">CNN News</a> ]]></Item>
```

I need to provide Edit functionality to allow a user to edit the url and the text of each item in the repeater. I don't want separate Edit/Save buttons for each row; too much clutter. I guess that means a single Edit/Save button, which would essentially result in the XML file being "created" anew on each Save. Or, might there be a better way to do this?

I guess I'm asking two things:

1. A design suggestion on how to make a list of URLs editable (both url and text). Two separate text boxes I guess?
2. How to handle edits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, two separate fields is the way to go here
2. As far as editing, you can have two panels for your `ItemTemplate`. One for **View** and one for **Edit**. The **Edit** panel's visibility is set to false by default. Each row has an "Edit" button with the item's ID as its `CommandArgument`, that when pressed, you set a Session variable with the ID of the item clicked. Then when you rebind your repeater, you check each item's ID against the Session edit ID variable. If they match, you set the **View** panel's visibility to false and the **Edit** panel's visibility to true. The **Edit** panel has two buttons, one for Save and one for Cancel. Once the user clicks Save or Edit, you do any back-end processing, clear the Session variable and rebind the repeater. Although there are built in controls that have edit functionality "built-in", I find the control I am alloted by using the Repeater is superior.

I've used this method numerous times and it works great!

If you need any code to illustrate any of the point above, feel free to ask.

As a side not, your XML looks a little strange. There doesn't seem to be a parent node to represent each URL/ID pair. It this an oversight, a typo, or am I missing something here?

**EDIT:**

This is a good way to utilize ViewState in your scenario:

```
    private enum PageStates
    {
        None = 0,
        View = 1,
        Edit = 2
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The current state of the page
    /// </summary>
    private PageStates PageState
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["PageState"] == null)
                ViewState["PageState"] = PageStates.View; //default to view state

            return (PageStates)ViewState["PageState"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["PageState"] = value;
        }
    }
```

By encapsulating ViewState access in a property, any changes to the method of storing the variable (Session, DB, etc) are abstracted away from any code that accesses it.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I'm trying to avoid an edit button for each row and the need for individual clicks for each edit. Too many buttons, too many clicks.

Comment: And, my XML has a <Items> parent node.     `<Portfolio>
  <Items><ID>0</ID>
    <Item><![CDATA[<a target='blank' href="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</a> ]]></Item>
  </Items></Portfolio>

Comment: So you want one button that turns on the edit functionality for all rows, as well as one Save button to save all the rows? If this is the case, you can still use the pattern I suggested, just without a Session ID variable. You can use a Page-level ViewState variable to determine what state the page is in Edit or View. Does that fit your requirements?

Comment: Yes, one button for both. I'll look into ViewState as I've never used it before.

Comment: `ViewState` variables are a page level variable that is stored in the `ViewState` on the page. I've updated my answer to show you an example of the implementation.

Comment: I've decided to spawn a new page for edits. It was getting too messy to have it all on the same page and still retain the layout.

On the new page, I'll make all the fields editable, and with a single Save action write them all back to the XML file. I guess that means I won't need to use ViewState, right?

Comment: A new/related question: Using the ID, should I loop through the repeater and update each XML element, or loop the XML file and find the match in the repeater? Or, skip all that and create the XML file again?

Comment: Correct, you will no longer need the ViewState, as you no longer need to maintain the state of the page. You might as well skip all the looping/searching in the repeater and recreate the file. Also, if my answers have helped you, you can upcote the answer or, even better, choose it as the answer. Thanks!